# Anatomically Correct Moon People

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fantasy-races, anatomy, anatomically-correct

The moon people are strange extraterrestrials. They originated on the Earth, but now live on the Moon, which, despite its reduced gravity, still has an Earth-like atmosphere and ecosystem. They are tetrapodal and monkey-like in their external form, and about as tall as a human. Despite their outward appearance, they are internally distinct from tetrapods, due to having no liver and a minimal intestine, as well as being hermaphrodites. They have hair (or something like it) covering their body, most particulary under the chin, where it can grow down to their knees. This hair also extends to the large pouch they possess on their abdomen, which is can be used to store tools and other such object. They have an orthograde posture, and appear human-like. Their ears are divided into 3 pointed lobes, like a plane-leaf, and they have no eyes. Their tail is short and shaped like a cabbage. How could such a creature have arisen? Ignore how exactly they ended up on the Moon

Comment: Which trait exactly do you need help with? Simply listing all traits of the species seems a bit broad.

Comment: @Harabeck How could all these traits come together in a singular creature?

Comment: How they ended at the moon sounds like a pretty important thing, considering they've probably need to have developed from the ground up in there. Also they might have an exoskeleton to help with keeping their form (kinda like how arthropods can survive in vacuum for a few seconds without, you know, having their bodies try to occupy all the space ).

Comment: @ProjectApex The version of the moon they live on has an atmosphere and an entire ecosystem, so no exoskeleton is needed

Comment: Then it might be best to give us some more detail on this moon ecosystem and potentially even how it came to be. The chin hair can easily be explained by sexual selection, but things like the lack of a liver, which on earth regulates several chemical levels in the blood, and very small intestines might indicate their overall internal functioning is completely different, potentially coming from an ancestor that never touched on earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are echinoderms.**

[image: brittle star]

http://www.waikikiaquarium.org/experience/animal-guide/invertebrates/echinoderms/brittle-stars/

Lack of competition let the echinoderms take over the moon.  The terrestrial brittle stars walk on the lower most arms and usually use the uppermost to manipulate objects in the environment though they can be recruited for ambulation and the lower ones can be used for manipulation also.  All 4 are used to climb.  The upper most arm is smaller and for persons ready to see a human form seems to be the "head" though it is devoid of eyes, mouth or facial features characterizing a tetrapod face.

What appears to be hair are the legs and setae common to echinoderms, which in these moon creatures has hypertrophied in some parts of the body.  On the "head" these are sometimes used to carry a shell or stone in the manner of sea urchins.

The abdominal pouch is actually the ventral stomach which can be used to carry nonfood items.